# Android studio, if button doesn't have drawable

Tags: java, android

```
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {
            if (b4.getCompoundDrawables() == null) {
                if (turn == 1) {
                    turn = 2;
                    b4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iks);
                } else if (turn == 2) {
                    turn = 1;
                    b4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oks);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

I have drawable iks (X) and oks (O) (making X-O game), and I wanna use my IF command to check if b4 (button) already have background drawn on it, in order to be able to make only 1 change to button so you can't use button that is already been used again.

Comment: I found a way, I'll try by using boolean for each button to see if it's already pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBackground` to see whether the background drawable has been set:

```
if (b4.getBackground() == null)
```

However, you should really design a "model" for your tic-tac-toe game.

Here's an idea:

Store a 2D int array that can store three possible values: 0, 1 and 2. 0 means nothing in the square. 1 means there is a cross and 2 means there is a nought. You can create constants for these:

```
public static final int EMPTY = 0;
public static final int CROSS = 1;
public static final int NOUGHT = 2;
```

Expose a method called `updateArray(int x, int y, int value)` that updates the value at the specified `x` and `y` position.

Each time you call this method, set the drawable of the correct view.

Now to check whether there is nothing in a "square", you can just check the array for `EMPTY`.

Comment: Thanks... I gave it a break and came up with the idea of boolean for each button to see if pressed or not and it works... Thanks for reply and taking ur time :)